# Looking for book(s) specifically on learning the in's-out's of HTTPCONTEXT object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

The more I learn about .NET web developement, the more I come back to the HTTPCONTEXT object.  It seems that pretty much everything is in some form or fashion accessible through this object being that it all comes down to requests and responses.

Therefore, I was looking for any books that go into depth about how to utilize HTTPCONTEXT and all its objects.

Or if you think a more useful topic for learning core elements of .NET web development with ASP.NET and MVC would be appropriate please suggest.

**NOTE:  I am not referring to books on the larger topic of ASP.NET and MVC (as I have read these), I am looking for more narrowed topics to get down to learning specific areas to help me with these frameworks (such as my original request about learning the HTTPCONTEXT object.**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to learn more about web architecture and dig deeply into HTTP, I strongly suggest you to read this book:

- [HTTP: The Definitive Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1565925092)

It's not particularly about ASP.NET or ASP.NET MVC or any other framework, but it helps you to understand the protocol the web is build upon.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

http://www.msdn.com

While not a book, it most certainly has good information about HTTPContext.

Answer (score 1):

Whole ASP is around HttpContext object so any good decent ASP.Net book will teach you that. If you need something narrowed down to a particular Class in .Net see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.aspx) and check out this [Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972109.aspx) (Its old but still worth reading)